# How to get the latest value, as long as the latest Status doesn't meet a criteria on Sheet (via Query Formula)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the latest value, based on a criteria. However, the result must not exclude values where its status equals to X or Y.

I've prepared a sheet to demonstrate the problem.

This is the query formula I've been working on:

```
=Unique(QUERY(DB!$A:$M,"select C, A, D, I where not I matches 'Entregue' ", 1))
```

This is the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U8JZdEG0s-3VYCBLb3TgPqGWiOIVCNNC8I9lbT2i8g4/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please add expected results at your sheet and let us know when done.

Comment: Just did, @marikamitsos. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ! Would you be open to an answer usign [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) or do you exclusively want Google Sheets formulas?

Comment: Hi, @MateoRandwolf! I'd be open to a script, yes. I suppose that this'd be fired onOpen and when the user saves a new information, changing the origin of the data populating expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying with Apps Script and with some formulas I envetually came up with this two step process that I found to be the easier to build.

Basically, use your previour formula without `UNIQUE` to query the right date.

Then I used on another part of the sheet [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) and [SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) to filter this data from `QUERY`.

`SORT` will sort the values according to column 1 (A) in an ascending order and then `SORTN` will remove duplicate rows and show the latest one.

[image]

```
=QUERY(DB!$A:$M,"select C, A, D, I where not I matches 'Delivered' and not I matches 'Cancelled' ", 1)
```

```
=SORTN(SORT(A11:D,1,0),2^9,2,1,1)
```